# onclick="myfunction(1146, 'item1', '', '1143');" does not work BUT works if I edit it from console

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this button

```
<button type="button" onclick="myfunction(1146, 'item1', '', '1143');" id="myButton1" value="11.2" class="price_button" name="serviceButtonValue">
```

1. When the page loads and I click it for the first time, it does not work.
2. Now if I press f12 (*use the elements tab to change the html*), and delete the letter "m" from the `onclick="myfunction(..)` namespace and it becaomes `onclick="yfunction(..)`, I click again and get an error (duh!).
3. **The weird part:** If I put the missing "m" back so it becomes again `onclick="myfunction(..)` and click the button it will work.

What is happening? Why is it not working before the editing. Is editing the html from the console changing anything??

I also tried adding an alert before (again from console editor), so it becomes like this `"onclick="alert();myfunction(...)" and it works again!

**Some important bits:**

1. on the first click i do **not** get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined"
2. myfunction() is in an external `.js` file
3. the only error message i get is **after** i remove the "m"
4. does not enter the myfcuntion at all. I have a `console.log(..);` and it does not output anything

**Fixed**

I changed the `<button...>..</button>` to a `<div...>..</div>` and its working fine.... anyone knows why?

Comment: Would be very interesting to see a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of that. :)

Comment: Can you add your JS code?

Comment: When you do `delete the letter "m" from the onclick="myfunction(..)`, did you changed name at function definition?

Comment: @Siguza i tried replicating it in jsfiddle but it works fine. I mean If I could produce the error then I guess ill probably solve it! :)

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar when I did the change from the developer tools it produced an error, because the function was not there anymore, the function is myfunction but it was looking for yfunction, when i put the m back, it works fine!

Comment: @Alexandros How do you include your JS in your HTML page? External script? `<script>` tag in `<head>`? Or in `<body>`?

Comment: @Siguza external `.js` file

Comment: Is there maybe a different function called myfunction?

Comment: @g_m I searched my entire source and could not find anything. Also the `.js` file has only one function named myfunction

Comment: Are you 100% sure it doesn't enter your function, but outputs nothing? Did you try putting breakpoints in your function in the developper tools (F12)?

Comment: @Jordumus yep, i added a `console.log('hello');` right after the starting bracket `{` of the myfunction and does not output anything

Comment: Try changing the name of your function to something abstract, both in your html and in your js.

Comment: In the button in the HTML source or do you add it with JavaScript?

Comment: @Jordumus what do you mean something abstract :) like addtocart(..) ?
also do you mean to make the change live? or from my files

Comment: Have you left a `console.log` or similar `console` instruction in your function?  If so, that will fail if developer tools are not enabled.  (Edit: just seen your comment from 3 minutes ago, that's your issue)

Comment: @freefaller yes i have, they are enabled i can see other console.logs

Comment: Also, please check that you didn't put any empty spaces in your function name (like this one: `​`) . try to select, you'll see there is a hidden character.

Comment: @Jordumus wouldnt that cause an uncaught error? also when i place the letter back it works as expected!

Comment: Last try: can you add an addEventListener to your javascript for that button, instead of the `onClick` attribute? (edit: spelling, too tired)

Comment: @Jordumus i added this `$(".myButton1").click(function() { alert('hi'); });` and still no luck..

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem — http://jsbin.com/dibuxofido/1/edit?html,output — please provide a test case that demonstrates the problem: http://sscce.org/

Comment: `$(".myButton1")` will find buttons with `class="myButton1"`.  You need `$("#myButton1")` to find `id="myButton1"`

Comment: @freefaller yes that was a mistype thats what i have..

Comment: @Quentin as I told to a previous comment i do not know what causes this, therefore cant reproduce it!

Comment: I'm interested, did you figure this out in the end?

Comment: @freefaller I changed the button to div and its (magically) working, any ideas why? :P

Comment: Nope - you have me stumped on that one @Alexandros